# ArrayOutOfBoundsExcetpion in command line arguments

Tags: java

in command line arguments i got  Exception in the thread main `java.lang.ArryINdexOutOfBoundsException`. How can i overcome this?

```
class p
{
    public static void main(String a[])throws Exception
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);

        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that array indexes start at 0? So you're asking for the second command line argument? That code will fail if there are fewer than two command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If you call the program with only one parameter, you have to use `Integer.parseInt(a[0]);`, because arrays in java are zero bases.

Also you should check the length of `a` before accessing an entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the two parameters from command prompt then your code will be successfully run like java className parameter1 parameter2 then you can access second parameter by using a[1].

other wise change a[1] to a[0] for first parameter.